# Conditions under which an $\eta$-quotient becomes a **weak** modular form (reference request for theorems similar to Ligozat's theorem)

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

For any $z \in \mathcal{H}$, let $q = e^{2\pi iz}$; and the eta function is defined as
${\displaystyle \eta (q) 
=q^{\frac {1}{24}}\prod _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(1-q^{n}\right).}$
By an $\eta$-quotient we mean a meromorphic function of the form
${\displaystyle f(z) =\prod_{0<\delta \mid N} \eta(q^{\delta})^{r_\delta}}$, where $N$ is a natural number and $r_{\delta}$'s are some integers.

Ligozat's theorem gives us some conditions under which an $\eta$-quotient is a **weak** modular form; it states that (You can find it in the book "Modular forms, A classical and computational introduction", by Lloyd Kilford (2008), section 5.2, pages 98-99):

Theorem 5.7 (**Ligozat** [Ligozat (1975)], quoted in [McMurdy (2001)]).
Let $N$ be a positive integer, and suppose that $f(z) =\prod_{0<\delta \mid N} \eta(q^{\delta})^{r_\delta}$ is an $\eta$-quotient which satisfies the following properties:

$$\sum_{0<\delta\mid N}\delta . r_{\delta} ≡ 0 \mod 24 $$
and
$$\sum_{0<\delta\mid N}\frac{N}{\delta} . r_{\delta} ≡ 0 \mod 24.$$

Then $f(z)$ is a **weak** modular form of weight $k:=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{0<\delta\mid N} r_{\delta}$, with level $N$ and charachter
$\chi(d)=\left(\dfrac{(-1)^k . \prod_{0<\delta\mid N} \delta^{r_{\delta}}}{d}\right)$;
i.e. for $z \in \mathcal{H}$
and $\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\ 
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}
\in \Gamma_0(N)$,
we have $f\left(\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}\right) = \chi(d)\left(cz+d\right)^{k} f(z)$.

---

---

Before this theorem is expressed in that book, it is stated that: "*There are **theorems** that tell us that certain $\eta$-products and $\eta$-quotients are (weak) modular forms; for instance, we quote the following result of Ligozat without proof:*", and then the above theorem is stated.

I'm very interested and curious about **those similar theorems**, where can I find those theorems, and see more general and generalized forms of Ligozat's theorem? **Are there other forms of **Ligozat's theorem** in which the modulus in the congruence conditions (that is $24=4\times 2 \times 3$), is replaced by the number $4pq$, for some prime numbers?** Any reference containing any kinds of similar theorems (theorems that are stating that under some condition an $\eta$-quotient is a **weak** modular form) are welcome.

EDIT (I): Are there other forms of **Ligozat's theorem** in which the modulus in the congruence conditions (that is $24=4\times 2 \times 3$), is replaced by a modulus that is divisible by two different odd prime numbers $p\neq p'$?** (Of course we can give a positive answer to this question just by replacing the modulus by $5\times 24$, and the same conditions work trivially, but I mean something with different congruence conditions, actually I am looking for other generalized versions and analogous theorems). Also, any English reference that contains proof of Ligozat's theorem is welcome.

---

---

The references mentioned in the book are the two that I have written below:

- Ligozat, G. (1975). [Courbes modulaires de genre 1](http://archive.numdam.org/article/MSMF_1975__43__5_0.pdf) (Société Mathématique de France, Paris), Bull. Soc. Math. France, Mém. 43, Supplément au Bull.
  Soc. Math. France Tome 103, no. 3.
- McMurdy, K. (2001). [A Splitting Criterion for Galois Representations Associated to Exceptional Modular Forms](https://phobos.ramapo.edu/%7Ekmcmurdy/research/short_thesis.pdf), Ph.D. thesis, U.C. Berkeley

On pages 28 (=page 25 of the pdf, proposition 3.1.1) and 31 (=page 28 of the pdf, proposition 3.2.1) of the first reference, and on page 29 of the second reference (theorems 7.4 and 7.5), there are versions of this theorem, which are not stronger than the version expressed in this question (I have not yet been able to find an English translation for the first reference).

Comment: I think the congruence mod 24 is unavoidable, because the transformation formula for $\eta$ involves a $24$-th root of unity (which is related to the modularity of $\Delta=\eta^{24}$). So I guess $4pq$ will not be sufficient. I don't know other theorems, but I can mention a similar situation where we even have a necessary and sufficient condition for modularity, namely, for products of Siegel units. Their definition is formally the same as $\eta$ except they have weight 0, not $1/2$. Kubert and Lang have worked out the condition in their book "Modular units", Chapter 3, Section 5.

Comment: However, eta quotients are a bit different in that one considers $\eta(q^d)$. For Siegel units, one rather considers products of them, of the form $g_x^{r_x}$, indexed by $x \in (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^2$. That being said, I just found results more recent than Ligozat on the Wikipedia page of the Dedekind eta function. The difficulty of your problem is that $\eta$ itself is modular but for a non-congruence subgroup.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thanks for your fruitful comments. I have a similar opinion about modulus, but since it is something like an observation, and I did not have a strong argument or evidence about it, I asked this question. Maybe I should change my questions a bit about this so that the modulus is replaced by a modulus that is divisible by two different odd prime numbers $p\neq p'$. (In addition, I did not realize that I had used the "$q$" symbol in my questions before, and for example, it might be better to use the "$p'$" symbol instead.)

Comment: is theorem 14 on page 6 of my https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0158.pdf the sort of thing you’re looking for? if so i think a good reference to check (if you haven’t looked through it already) is Kohler’s “Eta products and theta series identities: examples”

Comment: @Davood I think your question about arbitrary modulus is fine. I looked at Ligozat's statement and the integers $r_\delta$ are $\geq 0$ in his theorem (also, it's for weight $k=2$). Do you want to consider $\eta$-quotients, not just $\eta$-products?

Comment: @Davood If you consider $\eta$-quotients (that is, with possibly negative $r_\delta$'s), then you should add assumptions in the theorem, because an $\eta$-quotient need not be holomorphic at the cusps. The conditions for this are given in the article linked to in alpoge's comment.

Comment: @alpoge Thanks for introducing your beautiful paper. I was already familiar with Kohler's book; as you mentioned, there are so many many identities between $\eta$-quotients and Theta series, and I have already searched there considerably. I was careless in writing the question and I apologize for that, and I forgot to write the word "**weak**"; I'm looking for conditions under which $\eta$-quotients become a **weak modular form**. Then, if we are looking for modular forms, it is enough to add some conditions to guarantee holomorphicity (as you described in theorem 14).

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thanks for correcting the question. I was careless in writing the question and I apologize for that, and I forgot to write the word "**weak**"; I'm looking for conditions under which $\eta$-quotients become a **weak modular form**. Then, if we are interested in modular forms, we can easily consider the conditions for guaranteeing holomorphicity. Under these conditions, the $\eta$-quotients and $\eta$-products are almost the same, and any theorem about $\eta$-products is also welcome.